# I am trying to install docker on centos8 vagrantbox facing the error 'Downloading successful, but checksum doesn't match'

Tags: docker, centos8

```
[MIRROR] containerd.io-1.2.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm: Downloading successful, but checksum doesn't match. Calculated: ece851b2b2defa24eb3b817b14d97f31f4043a713d7367972bd2c1ef4f2788b8(sha256)  Expected: 7bd1d8da7d896ead55fdea3a42100eac4c4d7800f958d3ae056d40268dec4636(sha256)
(8/21): python3-policycoreutils-2.9-9.el8.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                             107 kB/s | 2.2 MB     00:21
[MIRROR] containerd.io-1.2.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm: Downloading successful, but checksum doesn't match. Calculated: 3928fc6c58817b02602a249e512d7e99b7c3fe06ea5d9ff3ad46e25984ff8141(sha256)  Expected: 7bd1d8da7d896ead55fdea3a42100eac4c4d7800f958d3ae056d40268dec4636(sha256)
[MIRROR] docker-ce-18.09.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm: Downloading successful, but checksum doesn't match. Calculated: 3ddabd445a05b85aeba128da42283d3285ca8055e6a201139ee49b682942ba43(sha256)  Expected: 6034f83c3bf3d5d31120ef36b3172dbb28d1ac8ae3699ed8cb33924dcef0d17a(sha256)
[MIRROR] containerd.io-1.2.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm: Downloading successful, but checksum doesn't match. Calculated: 3914815a5c9756672d6f046929335ddff86607c29ac8a3c3fc12452a69952bf7(sha256)  Expected: 7bd1d8da7d896ead55fdea3a42100eac4c4d7800f958d3ae056d40268dec4636(sha256)
[FAILED] containerd.io-1.2.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm: No more mirrors to try - All mirrors were already tried without success
(10-11/21): docker-ce-18.09.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                50% [==============================================                                              ] 1.4 MB/s |  50 MB     00:35 ETA
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'yum clean packages'.
Error: Error downloading packages:
  Cannot download Packages/containerd.io-1.2.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm: All mirrors were tried

Error: Transaction test error: package selinux-policy-targeted-3.14.3-41.el8_2.5.noarch does not verify: Header SHA1 digest: BAD (Expected ab8b3fe6b75faa65c89e64ec34986ee49924f982 != 3716bcc257255e43bc9ace1b9c4aecb6fcba3e61) package python3-policycoreutils-2.9-9.el8.noarch does not verify: Header SHA1 digest: BAD (Expected af32d12b99154706740619e0ac39289c009f1aa9 != faa84ee41c25523f2a05358d172f124370c18f99) package containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64 does not verify: no digest
```

'''   Please help me to install docker on centos8 to fix this issue SHA1 digest: BAD '''

Comment: What method are you using to install Docker?

Comment: Installing by using repository method

Comment: That tells me nothing. How about you paste all the command you used in the question?

Comment: sudo yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2, 
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo,
sudo yum -y install docker-ce --nobest

Comment: What version of CentOS are you using?

Comment: centos8 (vagrantbox)

Comment: Please edit your Question to include all relevant information. Do not provide clarifications in comments only.

Comment: I have edited my question, I have tried to install containerd manually but fcing SHA1 digest: BAD error, please help me to fix this iisue.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing packages `containerd` manually:

```
yum clean packages #clean packages from failed install
dnf install https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64.rpm #install newest containerd manually
sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli #install Docker daemon and CLI
```

Links:

- [Install Docker on CentOS](https://pocketadmin.tech/en/centos-8-install-docker/)
- [Docker documentation for installation
  on CentOS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/)
- [Docker CentOS repository](https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/)

Comment: Error: Transaction test error:
  package selinux-policy-targeted-3.14.3-41.el8_2.5.noarch does not verify: Header SHA1 digest: BAD (Expected ab8b3fe6b75faa65c89e64ec34986ee49924f982 != 3716bcc257255e43bc9ace1b9c4aecb6fcba3e61)
  package python3-policycoreutils-2.9-9.el8.noarch does not verify: Header SHA1 digest: BAD (Expected af32d12b99154706740619e0ac39289c009f1aa9 != faa84ee41c25523f2a05358d172f124370c18f99)
  package containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64 does not verify: no digest

Comment: That sentence makes no sense. did you try my solution and it failed with the same error message or do you think that what you did previously constitutes installing `containerd` manually?

Comment: When I tried your solution to install containerd.io manually I face the above error